Azure Cosmos DB for PostgreSQL | USER postgres Login | pgAdmin 4 OR Azure CLI unable to login
After creating Azure Cosmos DB for PostgreSQL, we have two users

citus
postgres

Here we are trying to assign superuser role to citus.
For assigning superuser role user should have superuser role permission.
Only postgres user has superuser role.
We are trying to login with postgres user but unable to login. (Using Azure CLI and pgAdmin4)
pgAdmin 4 tool used to login but it didn't work.


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.


If you try with any other instead of superuser then you may get above error. But According to the MS document super user is not accessible in azure PostgreSQL - Flexible Server. But according to the MS document if CREATE EXTENSION fails with a permission denied error, try the create_extension() function instead. So, use below query to create extension:
SELECT create_extension('vector');

then the extension will create successfully as shown below:

For checking if you run create extension vector query after running above query you will get extension "vector" already exists as output.
